# Creating new branch doesn't create brach for all modules in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, on the right bottom, when i click on the branch name, a list of branches will show up, and there is a "+New Branch" function on top of the list. When i click on this "New Function", and put new branch name, for some projects, it will create a new branch for every module. But for some projects, it only creates a new branch for the current module where the file is open at. How could that happen? I thought it should always create new branch for all modules? If it only creates a new branch for current module only, then it's a pain to create a new branch for each module one by one.

Comment: Branch can not be created for each module unless these modules are come from different git repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i found the issue. There is a setting beside the "Git Branches" list. The setting has an option "Execute branch operations on all roots". Once i selected this option, it created new branches for all modules.